# How can I create a sequence of registered process names in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

At the moment I am using the following to create and register processes individually:

```
register(name, spawn(fun() -> myfun())).
```

I would like to create a list of N registered Pids with names as follows:

```
pid1
pid2
pid3
.
.
.
pidN
```

Can anyone recommend a way of doing this?

Comment: Be aware the atoms are **NOT** garbage collected so they never go away. You should be careful when creating atoms dynamically in your program. If it is just for a fixed number, as it seems to be in this case, then there should be no problems.

Comment: Consider using gproc and have names like {foo, 3} to avoid what @rvirding said: https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to spawn multiple processes for the same function you can use a list comprehension and use concatenation of strings and `list_to_atom/1`:

```
[register(list_to_atom("pid" ++ integer_to_list(X)), spawn(fun() -> myFun() end)) || X <- lists:seq(1,10)].
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use following:

if you want to execute same function in multiply processes and register each process under different names:

```
lists:foreach( 
   fun( Name ) -> 
      register( Name, spawn( fun() -> myfun() end ) ) 
   end, 
   [ pid1, pid2, pid3 ] ).
```

or if you want to execute different functions in different processes:

```
lists:foreach( 
   fun( { Name, Func } ) -> 
      register( Name, spawn( fun() -> Func() end ) ) 
   end, 
   [ { pid1, f1 }, { pid2, f2 }, { pid3, f3 } ] ).
```

( f1, f2, f3 - are functions )

and finally, if you want to execute same function in N processes, you might do next:

```
N = 20, %number of processes
lists:map( 
   fun( Num ) -> 
      register( 
         list_to_atom( "pid" ++ integer_to_list( Num ) ), 
         spawn( fun() -> myfun() end ) ) 
   end, 
   lists:seq( 1, N ) ).
```